# Get AttributeError when producing seasonally adjusted time series with statsmodels on python 3.4

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4, statsmodels

I am trying to produce seasonally adjusted time series with statsmodels function tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis. The following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

rng = pd.date_range('31/3/2011', periods=17, freq='Q')
non_adjusted = pd.Series([9.9, 9.4, 9.4, 9.9, 10.6, 10.3, 10.2, 10.7, 11.4, 10.8, 10.5, 10.7, 11.0, 10.1, 9.8, 10.0, 10.2], index=rng)
sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(non_adjusted).seasadj
```

when run with python 3.4 and statsmodels 0.6.1, gives this error:

```
    ...
--> 218         for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
    ...    
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

The code works fine with python 2.7, but I would like to use python 3.4. Am I doing something wrong and how could I fix it?

Comment: Clearly `statsmodel` isn't Python3 compatible, as `iteritems()` was removed in 3.x family. You may try to modify module source yourself (e.g. with `2to3` tool).

Comment: statsmodels has been python 3 compatible for several years (with 2to3), and has common codebase working for python 2 and 3 for a year. I'm using python 3.4 as my main statsmodels development python version. If there is a problem, then it's in a part that doesn't have test coverage on TravisCI https://travis-ci.org/statsmodels/statsmodels and its a BUG that should be reported.